# Problems with Vista and displaying webpages

Tags: windows-vista, router, wireless-networking

I have Windows Vista on my computer, and it says it has a very good connection to my wireless router, but it doesn't display any webpages in Firefox or IE. It just says "Can't find this page".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

do you get a response when you ping a website?

open a command prompt and type: `ping www.yahoo.com`

if you DO get a response, you may have to reset/repair the TCP/IP Stack:

Here's a tutorial:

**[Reinstall and Reset TCP/IP (Internet Protocol) in Windows Vista, 2003 and XP](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/06/19/reinstall-and-reset-tcpip-internet-protocol-in-windows-vista-2003-and-xp/)**

then open an elevated command prompt and use the following command:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

this will clear the DNS resolver cache.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you are connected to your router does not mean that your router is connected to the internet.

First steps...

Try visiting http://216.239.59.104

If you see nothing, it is possible:

- You have incorrect manual settings.
- DHCP is providing the wrong settings.
- Your router is not connected to the internet.

If you see Google

- Your routers DNS settings are wrong.
- DHCP has provided the wrong DNS settings

Have you got your DNS server set up correctly?

If you have been messing around with settings, it is sometimes worth resetting the TCP/IP stack when you have random problems... but it may not help. Go to an elevated command prompt and type `netsh int ip reset`

If any of this helps, or if it doesn't, please give feedback in comments and I will see what else I can do to help.